# What does String[ ]s = t.split(" ") mean/do?

Tags: java

Im working on programming for class, and we are looking at the sample code provided that takes the daily earnings for 4 weeks and prints out the day with the highest earnings. The program uses a dat file to read in the information and print the results. What I would like to understand is what exactly does String[ ]s = t.split(" ") do? It doesn't seem to be an array..

Data File

```
4
1300 1500 1200 1600 1800 900 1400
1200 1400 1500 1600 1100 1450 1475
1745 2534 2000 2100 2400 1975 1823
2231 1992 2000 2345 2435 1982 2500
```

The first number in the data file lists the number of lines (Weeks) to follow. Each line after that contains 7 numbers each correlating to a day of the week Sunday - Saturday.

Main Code from practice set. I added comments for each line, to fully explain my problem.

The line I dont understand is `String []s = t.split(" ");`

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;  


public class BestDay {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(new File("bestday.dat"));  //Imports File

        int count = 0; //Basic Counter for While loop
        int totalWeeks = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine().trim()); //Number of Weeks from First Line of Data File (4)
        while(count < totalWeeks) {    //Runs While loop as long as times is greater than count 
            count++; //Increments Count     

            String t = kb.nextLine().trim(); // pulls in the next line as a string and trims blank spaces
            String []s = t.split(" "); //Not Sure what is happening here) Someone Explain pls. 
            int most = Integer.parseInt(s[0]); //Takes each number and registers it as Int
            int day = 0; //Sets an int for later comparison
            for(int i=1; i<7; i++) { //for loop runs 7 times one for each day of the week for every 1 while loop run
                int next = Integer.parseInt(s[i]); //brings in each other integer. 
                if (next > most) {// compares it 
                    most=next; //If next is more than most then sets most to next
                    day=i; //sets day to i basically telling which day was the highest value on
                }
            }
            switch (day) {
                case 0: out.println("SUNDAY"); break; //looks at each case with Day and prints out the right case.
                case 1: out.println("MONDAY"); break;
                case 2: out.println("TUESDAY"); break;
                case 3: out.println("WEDNESDAY"); break;
                case 4: out.println("THURSDAY"); break;
                case 5: out.println("FRIDAY"); break;
                case 6: out.println("SATURDAY"); break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Expected Output

```
THURSDAY
WEDNESDAY
MONDAY
SATURDAY
```

Comment: See the documentation for [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): it splits a string using a regex

Comment: As the name suggests, it just splits the given string on the passed delimiter (in this case space " "). The delimiter can be a regex.

Comment: And returns the number of tokens returned in an array.

Comment: If you even **know** the method name, then why, I ask, **why** isn't your **very first attempt** to read the documentation? Is that really so hard?

Comment: "*What does String[ ]s = t.split(“ ”) mean/do?*" what do you think `t.split(" ")` could mean?

Comment: When you see a method you don't understand, you can do `<ctrl>+<click>` on the method and it will show you the code, and possibly it's Javadoc.  You don't have to wonder what a method does when it is well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Javadocs for `String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

Essentially, it tokenizes the target string into separate strings which were joined by the argument regular expression.

For example:

```java
"foo bar gah".split(" "); // => { "foo", "bar", "gah" }
"Mississipian".split("i"); // => { "M", "ss", "ss", "pp", "an" }
```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): it splits a string using a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). Specifically (as per the docs):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

In this case it simply splits a line from your file (such as `1300 1500 1200 1600 1800 900 1400`) on the specified pattern (in this case a `" "`) and returns an array of the individual strings. e.g.

```
{"1300", "1500", "1200", "1600", "1800", "900", "1400"}
```

Your first port of call for any "what does this java function do" question should be the java documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at official java documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Small snipped:

```
String[] parts = "123   156";    
String[] parts = string.split("   ");
```

`parts` will be an array of 2 elements containing `"123"` and `"456"` string respectively. The argument passed as input is used by split method to match the given regular expression (in my example a simple token string).

Answer (score 0):

String.split splits the given string using a delimiter and stores it in an array. In your case, its space. So using it on the 2nd line would provide you this array s[] = { 1300, 1500, 1200, 1600, 1800, 900, 1400 }

From javadoc 
String.split(String regex) 
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

(Next time read the docs)